# Dynamic Data Exchange (DDE) - Still Relevant?

Tags: windows, dde

Is there any reason to use [Dynamic Data Exchange (DDE)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Data_Exchange) in a modern Windows application?

If not, what alternative technology would you use instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Modern code uses COM for this. There is a tall stack of defined COM interfaces that you implement to receive the sort of stuff that DDE can deliver.