# What happends to opened DDE Channels if the application that opened them crashed?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, dde

I'm adding DDE for my app (C# 3.5) and sometimes when I open thousands (6000) of DDE channels it works, and sometimes, especially during debugging and excel crashes, it only gives me some of the items.

I suspect that the DDE channels are still "active" in Windows and when I try to open more I reach the DDE channels limit (10,000) and then not all have data.

Is there a way to "clean" the DDE engine in Windows, so I'll start fresh? or is restarting Windows the only solution?

Comment: If you are using C# 3.5 you should not be using DDE, since it is deprecated. I bet you could do what you want using OLE. Lookup COM-Interop for Exel for more information. See also this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2442586/dynamic-data-exchange-dde-still-relevant/2442598#2442598

Comment: DDE is the goto of interop.  Watch out, that raptor will eat you any moment now.

Comment: For "deprecated", substitute "obsolete since 15 years ago"

Comment: In 2011, your question reads like "I suspect that the memory control blocks are still 'active' in DOS and when I try to open more I reach the 64KB limit"

Comment: Come on people, do you think I WANT to add DDE support? Sometimes we have a little thing called backward compatibility...

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the open source NDde (http://ndde.codeplex.com/) then you can use the DdeClient class which implements the IDisposable pattern.  Then use the client inside a using block.  This effectively creates a finally block which should close the connection if an exception is thrown.  E.g.,

```
using (DdeClient client = new DdeClient(DDE_SERVER_NAME, dataField))
{
    client.Connect();

    string data = client.Request("xyz", DDE_TIMEOUT);
}
```

However, I've experienced the same thing though with data not being consistently returned but I not opening thousands of connections so it may be a different issue.

Comment: I'm writing the DDE Server, not the Client - and the client crashes.